# SoftKeyboard Questions

Tags: android, keyboard

So , I played with SoftKeyboard Demo Project , and I have 5 Questions and 1 Problem:

1) My problem , when typing a Word , and switchting to Symbol Keyboard , Type a Symbol , the previous Word Typed is Removed , Exepted If : i Type the Word >> Select in the Suggestion List >> Switch to Symbol , in this Case the Word is Not Removed , What Handle This?

2) How to change the Background Key Color ? , Eg. : Like in CyanogenMode Keyboard , Keys are Gray Dark and Shift-EnterSpace etc are More Dark , i mean the Background Color of the Keys , Not an Icon

3) I managed to get a Popup for More Keys when Long Press on a Key , Eg. : 'a' , the Popup appear and work Fine , But a Cross Icon(like in Widows) Appear to close the Popup , How to Make the Popup Close Automatically when releasing the Key , like in CM Keyboard ?

4) How to handle Long Press on Space/Enter , Eg. : to Change Language Or Show Input Settings?

5) Where can I find all Corresponding Keycode List ? Eg.: 'a' = 97 ?

6) Does SoftKeyboard Support External Dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Clone this `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME` will answer almost all the questions above, this is android default keyboard.