# Android Softkeyboard Style

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i've slightly altered the layout of the Softkeyboard example but I can't fathom how to change the colour of certain keys. (BG or FG, etc, anything distinguishable)

There doesn't seem to be the options when looking at the manual:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html

Searching here and I found:

[SoftKeyboard Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171639/softkeyboard-questions)

leading to:

http://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/

I've been through many of the files in that project but to be honest its somewhat overwhelming and will / would take me a long time to work it out, so i'm wondering if anyone could either point me to the right bit of code in that or other please?

EDIT:

*www.mindfiresolutions.com/Setting-keyboard-key-background-image-1876.php*

*stackoverflow.com/questions/18187598/how-to-set-different-key-background-for-every-key-in-android-custom-keyboard*

*stackoverflow.com/questions/18243323/keybackground-for-special-keys-android-keyboard*

EDIT:
A complete hack but i'm using something like this for now... (until better solution)

*stackoverflow.com/questions/6000543/customize-the-appearance-of-a-key*

```
            String s;
            List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
            for(Key key: keys) {
                if(key.label != null){
                    s=key.label.toString();
                    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
                        s = Character.toString((char) key.codes[0]);
                        canvas.drawText(s, key.x + (key.width/2), key.y+(key.height/2)+12, paint);
                    }
                }
            }
```